# Set of non invertible operators on $V$ is not a subspace of $\mathcal{L}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional and $\dim V>1$ . Prove that the set of noninvertible operators $A:=\{\phi \in \mathcal{L}(V)| \phi \ \text{non invertible}\}$ on $V$ is not a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V,V)$. I would like to know if my proof holds, please.

As $V$ is finite dimensional, then consider a basis of $V$: $(v_1,...,v_n)$. Define $\phi, \phi ' \in A$ as:

$\phi(v_1)=0, \phi(v_i)=v_i, i=2,...,n$

$\phi'(v_1)=v_1, \phi'(v_i)=0, i=2,...,n$

Clearly $\phi$ is not injective as $\phi(v_1)=0$ (so not invertible) and $\phi'$ is not injective as well (because $\phi'(v_i)=0$ for $i=2,...,n$).

But, $(\phi+\phi')(v_i)=v_i, i=1,...,n$ is an identity application and so invertible. Therefore, $A$ is not closed under addition and we conclude that $A$ is not a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for your feedback!